# Opentype `name` record used for CSS

Tags: css, opentype

I am trying to use my font for CSS and encounter a little bit of problem. It seems that putting non-standard values for "Typographic Subfamily" (`name` ID = 17) will make the font unloadable in CSS, e.g. "700W", "Sans", "Serif" etc. (Tested on Google Chrome).

I would like to ask what is the OpenType name that is used for CSS `font-family`? It seems to be using "Font Family" (`name` ID = 1) but for font with non-standard ID 17 values, it is unrecognized on my systen.

Note: I know @font-face is available but it is unfeasible to load as webfont.

Edit: The font link is here: https://github.com/nightFurySL2001/maoken-heavy-labourer. Loading `Maoken Heavy Labourer Gothic`, `Maoken Heavy Labourer - Gothic`, `Maoken Heavy Labourer Gothic Regular`, `猫啃网扛重族—黑`, `猫啃网扛重族` or any other combinations of name ID 16/17 and languages would not load the font (`MaokenHeavyLabourer-Gothic-Regular.ttf`).

Edit 2: Assuming the font is installed on a Windows machine and we are trying to load the font similar to how `font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial;` can be loaded. Directly using `name` ID = 16 + 17 could not load the font in Chrome.

Comment: You're going to have to show some code here, because CSS shouldn't care in the slightest about the `name` table, it only cares about what _you_ say is going to be its identifier in your `@font-face` rule. You declare what the `font-family` string is that should be associated with the `src` you indicate, and then any and all page CSS will make use of that font-face when you use that same font-family string in your page CSS. The "actual" name of the font is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans As I said, I know `@font-face` is available but the font is too large to be used for `@font-face`, so only `font-family` is available. We know that the end users will be installing the font on their own, but I could not load the font with just `font-family` and without the ability to deliver webfont I am unable to use `@font-face`.

Comment: No it isn't - if your font is too large, then you can still use `@font-face` just fine (as long as you can legally use that font online) as long as you should remember to [subset your font](https://markoskon.com/creating-font-subsets/) (if allowed by the font's subsetting permission bits), and use WOFF2's unicode ranges, so your page can load "only the parts of your font that it's going to actually need".

Comment: I understand, but due to this is a CJK font, subsetting won't solve it (even the subsetted font is 23MB) and will require dynamic subsetting. We had made sure those that used our site already have the required font installed legally, so we do not want to use `@font-face` to just load a local font. Please assume the font is pre-installed on a Windows machine and we are trying to load the font similar to how `font-family: "Segoe UI", Arial;` can be loaded without any use of `@font-face`.

Comment: Please remember to put details like that in your post. Ideally, [from the get-go](/help/how-to-ask) (to prevent comment threads like this one), but it's never too late to edit your post, so please do so.

Comment: I've written you an answer based on checking what the OS calls each font, and that I've verified works both on Windows and on Mac, with an explanation of how you _can_ use WOFF2, even for CJK fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this question ended up as two separate questions.

For one, my font ended up loading *without* the word Heavy, i.e. only "Maoken Labourer Gothic" works on Chrome (but "Maoken Heavy Labourer - Gothic" do work on Firefox).

Secondly, font weights with the name ID 17 = "700W" (not my font but another proprietory font) can be loaded with only name ID 16, and then specify `font-weight` separately.

I would still like to know why why these problem happen.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you just need the font's system name for each OS, so:

- Windows: double-click the font file, then look at the "Font name". (or ask someone with windows to check). In this case, that's `Maoken Heavy Labourer - Ming`.
- Mac: open Font Book, then look at the full name in the preview on the right (or asks someone with a mac to check). In this case, that's `Maoken Heavy Labourer Ming`.

And then to make sure the font gets picked for all your users, you make sure your CSS uses *both* names, with whatever fallback stack you need, but if all your users have the font installed already (as per your comments) then there wouldn't really be a need for a fallback font at all, and setting it to something ridiculous makes a missing font the most obvious.

```css
p {
  font-family: "Maoken Heavy Labourer - Ming", "Maoken Heavy Labourer Ming", fantasy;
}
```

The one caveat is that you will need to do this for *every* locale that the font has a custom name in, because as a Chinese font this may present a different name in Windows/Mac with the OS language set to one of the many Chinese variants available to both operating systems.

Which is why using `@font-face` [with WOFF2 subsetting](https://markoskon.com/creating-font-subsets/) would be better, since *you* get to declare a name instead of having to rely on whatever the various OS names for it can be.

For CJK specifically, that means subsetting on lists of unicode points (not just "unicode blocks" like "CJK Unified Ideographs" but actual lists of individual code points and short ranges) to cover "the first 100 most commonly used characters in the language I'm using", "the next 100 most commonly used characters in the language I'm using", and so on, so that you actually serve very small fonts. And then you can also rely on the browser caching those small fonts, which means your users should:

1. not download the entire 80MB font's worth of data, because you are definitely not using every single character in the lexicon, and
2. not really notice any problems loading a page, as the fonts each page requires will only be a few small font chunks at a time.

Both Chinese and Japanese have frequency lists available online to make "determining which characters go in each font" fairly easy, and you can even play around with how many characters to put into each chunk.

Comment: For Windows, the problem turns out to be that using "Maoken Heavy Labourer - Ming" does not work in Chrome, it only accepts "Maoken Labourer Ming". I know that the font name depends on `name` ID = 1 but "Maoken Labourer Ming" is nowhere to be found in the font file. See https://imgur.com/a/cpR6qLB . Also, for font with multiple weights, this is the incorrect method as you will need to separate the font name and weight separately to `font-family:""` and `font-weight:700;`

Comment: I assume you also filed this on the chromium bug tracker then? Because Chrome should not be "doing its own thing", CSS delegates the lookup to the OS, and if Chrome isn't doing that correctly, that's a bug you should report (even if you need a workaround right now that isn't `@font-face` based. Which of course, again, is still the far better solution)

Comment: I did report it to Chrome, on https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1267532 . My problem mainly stem from the fact that the CSS that we were using are automatically generated from PHP, and the font family name is directly read from the font file, thus resulting in me trying to figure which `name` record to be used in CSS since none of the `name` record works. (but it did work for most other fonts so it's not a problem with my code)

Comment: nice, I see there's already some activity on it, hopefully they fix that soon. Chrome should not be using its own name resolution here.